# GCP: Security command center Admin Viewer role is not working

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I gave my security team group unit the role `roles/securitycenter.adminViewer` as described in gcp documentation found [here](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/access-control)

The objective is to let the security team view all the threats with SCC.

The problem that is even with this role they are having missing permissions error :

```
resourcemanager.folders.get
resourcemanager.folders.list
resourcemanager.organizations.get
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
```

I tried to add more rights with the role `roles/browser` but they are more missing permissions popping.

I think I'm missing something, why the role `roles/securitycenter.adminViewer` is not working ? Normally it should be enough to be able to view the SCC ?

Comment: What roles have you assigned and to what? What is the exact error message? What is reporting the error message? You mention assigning to a group. What kind of group? How are the users assigned to the group and how are they authenticating with Google Cloud? You left out all the important details.

Comment: Are you sure that you "add" browser role to your team group? I think you might have "replaced" it.

Comment: What are the permission of service-org-organization-id@security-center-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com SA at the Organization layer? As per the doc you shared SA suppose to have securitycenter.serviceAgent role at the organization level that consists of missing permission you had.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a bug with the roles of SCC in GCP found here [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177984871).

I created a custom role with the missing permissions and it worked.